# DepthPageTransformer from both side same effect?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The code for dept page transformation animation appears when slide to left, to achieve the similar effect when sliding to right I did work around but have no success.

[Depth Page Tranfomer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

I want the same effect when I back to previous image that is the coming image must zoom out and current image slide to right. Any solution or fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

This code solves the problem, but is written in C#,i use Xamarin.Android, but it should be easy to translate to java, because it is translated from Java.

It is a class derived from RecyclerView.ViewHolder because in my code I use a RecyclerView to display multiple ViewPager.

I implement the interfaces

```
ViewPager.IPageTransformer
ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
```

In Java are

```
ViewPager.PageTransformer
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
```

In the same class to know if this dragging to the right or to the left.
And the transformation change in the direction

```
   public class PhotoPaisViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    ViewPager.IPageTransformer,
    ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
{
    private static AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    /**
     * Generate a value suitable for use in {@link #setId(int)}.
     * This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.
     *
     * @return a generated ID value
     */
    public static int GenerateViewId()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            int result = sNextGeneratedId.Get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (sNextGeneratedId.CompareAndSet(result, newValue))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    public ViewPager Pager { get; private set; }
    // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
    public PhotoPaisViewHolder(View itemView)
        : base(itemView)
    {
        // This for support multiple pagers in the same RecyclerView
        Pager = itemView.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr1)
        {
            Pager.Id = PhotoPaisViewHolder.GenerateViewId();
        }
        else
        {
            Pager.Id = View.GenerateViewId();
        }
        Pager.AddOnPageChangeListener(this);
        Pager.SetPageTransformer(reverse, this);
    }
    //For control the transformation
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
    private int currentPos;
    private bool reverse;
    private bool dragging;

    public void TransformPage(View view, float position)
    {
        //   Console.WriteLine(position);
        int pageWidth = view.Width;

        if (position < -1)
        { // [-Infinity,-1)
          // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.Alpha = 0;
        }
        else if (position <= 0)
        { // [-1,0]
          // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            if (reverse)
            {
                TransformUpView(view);
            }
            else
            {
                TransformDownView(view, position, pageWidth);
            }
        }
        else if (position <= 1)
        { // (0,1]
          // Fade the page out.
            if (reverse)
            {
                TransformDownView(view, position, pageWidth);
            }
            else
            {
                TransformUpView(view);
            }
        }
        else
        { // (1,+Infinity]
          // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.Alpha = 0;
        }
    }
    private static void TransformDownView(View view, float position, int pageWidth)
    {
        view.Alpha = 1 - Math.Abs(position);
        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.TranslationX = pageWidth * -position;
        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.Abs(position));
        view.ScaleX = scaleFactor;
        view.ScaleY = scaleFactor;
    }
    private static void TransformUpView(View view)
    {
        view.Alpha = 1;
        view.TranslationX = 0;
        view.ScaleX = 1;
        view.ScaleY = 1;
    }
    public void OnPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {
        dragging = state == ViewPager.ScrollStateDragging;
    }
    public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
    {
        if (dragging)
        {
            if (position < currentPos)
            {
                if (reverse)
                {
                    reverse = !reverse;
                    Pager.SetPageTransformer(reverse, this);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!reverse)
                {
                    reverse = !reverse;
                    Pager.SetPageTransformer(reverse, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void OnPageSelected(int position)
    {
        currentPos = position;
    }
}
```